# Sort hash attending to two parameters

Tags: perl, sorting, perl-module

I have a hash with the keys in the following format:

```
scaffold_902_159
scaffold_2_1980420
scaffold_2_10
scaffold_10_402
```

I want to print out the hash sorted in the following format:

```
scaffold_2_10
scaffold_2_1980420
scaffold_10_402
scaffold_902_159
```

So first I have to order numerically attending to the first number and then attending to the last one. I don't want a regular expression searching for "scaffold_" since this may vary. I mean, I can have the hash with other format like "**blablabla_NUMBER_NUMBER**, or **blablablaNUMBER_NUMBER**". The last part of the key **_NUMBER**, is the only thing that is permanent.

I've this code but only sorts numerically attending to the first number:

```
my @keys = sort {
          my ($aa) = $a =~ /(\d+)/;
          my ($bb) = $b =~ /(\d+)/;
          $aa <=> $bb;
        } keys %hash;
foreach my $key (@keys) {
   print $key;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8556331/1331451 - You'd have to do some work for finding those numbers in your strings, but the accepted answer there is what you need construct-wise. You might want to combine that with a Schwartzian Transform.

Comment: Are there blablabla_NUMBER with fix occurrence or blablabla & NUMBER could get change like blablabla_blablabla_NUMBER?

Comment: @AbhiNickz, thinking a bit more on your question, maybe sometimes can happen that the middle number is not a number. These ocurrences should be appear at the end and sorted of course by the second number (which is always there)

Comment: We're having a bit of a discussion down on my answer about your last comment. Can you please clarify for us? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sort::Naturally](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Sort::Naturally qw(nsort);
my %hash = (
                scaffold_902_159 => 'v1',
                scaffold_2_1980420 => 'v2',
                scaffold_2_10 => 'v3',
                scaffold_10_402 => 'v4',
            );
print "$_\n" for nsort keys %hash;
```

Output:

```
scaffold_2_10
scaffold_2_1980420
scaffold_10_402
scaffold_902_159
```

---

As per your query, tried out some keys which did not have number in middle.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Sort::Naturally qw(nsort);
my @keys = qw(
    should_come_last_9999_0
    blablabla_10_403
    scaffold_902_159
    scaffold_2_1980420
    scaffold_2_10
    scaffold_10_402
    blablabla902_1
    blablabla901_3
);
print "$_\n" for nsort @keys;
```

Output:

```
blablabla_10_403
blablabla901_3
blablabla902_1
scaffold_2_10
scaffold_2_1980420
scaffold_10_402
scaffold_902_159
should_come_last_9999_0
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it and accept the answer if it works. Do you know what happen if you haven't a number in the middle number?

Comment: It will work. As the description of the module says `Sort::Naturally -- sort lexically, but sort numeral parts numerically`.

Answer (score 3):

This sorts on two columns, and uses the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to create those columns from your strings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @keys = qw(
    scaffold_902_159
    scaffold_2_1980420
    scaffold_2_10
    scaffold_10_402
);

@keys =
    map { $_->[0] }                                               # transform back
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }           # sort
    map {                                                         # transform
        m/(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))/;
        [ $_, ( defined $2 ? ( $1, $2 ) : ( 0xffffffff, $1 ) ) ]
    } @keys;

say for @keys;
```

Output:

```
scaffold_2_10
scaffold_2_1980420
scaffold_10_402
scaffold_902_159
```

The data structure returned by the initial transformation `map` looks like this:

```
[ 'scaffold_902_159', 902, 159 ]
```

The `sort` uses that to first sort by index 1 (the `902`) above with the numerical sort `<=>`. That operator returns `0` if both the RHS and the LHS are equal, so the or `||` continues with the right expression, It then sorts on index 2 (the `159`).

Because you said the first number is optional, and if only the second number is there those elements should come last, we have to substitute a very high number for that. Without going into 64bit integers, `0xffffffff` is the highest number we can make.

The second `map` pulls the full key out of index `0` of the array reference.

If we add some other things to the input, like the `blablablaNUMBER_NUMBER` you suggested, it will still only sort *on the numbers* and ignore the string part completely.

```
my @keys = qw(
    should_come_last_9999_0
    blablabla_10_403
    scaffold_902_159
    scaffold_2_1980420
    scaffold_2_10
    scaffold_10_402
    no_first_number_1
);
```

Here's the output:

```
scaffold_2_10
scaffold_2_1980420
scaffold_10_402
blablabla_10_403
blablabla902_1
scaffold_902_159
should_come_last_9999_0
no_first_number_1
```

Comment: The comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527747/sort-hash-attending-to-two-parameters/40528064#comment68296100_40527747 invalidates my answer.

Comment: I noticed that Sort::Naturally does a really good job with such set of data. See the output of the second section of my answer.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak it does. But I understood the question as it shouldn't sort on the words, which yours does. I think that was a bit ambiguous in the question. What's going to happen with the `no_first_number_1` in your solution?

Comment: `blablabla_10_403,no_first_number_1,scaffold_2_10,scaffold_2_1980420,scaffold_10_402,scaffold_902_159,should_come_last_9999_0` which is correct I think because it sorted the first column alphabetically.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I think that's wrong. OP's comment says _These ocurrences should be appear at the end and sorted of course by the second number (which is always there)_. That sounds like my last output. But it seems OP either explained that wrong, or hasn't noticed yet. I hope they come back to at least clarify... :D

Comment: Oh I see. Ha! Let's wait.

Comment: Hi again, so..probably I've explained myself wrong, or not in detail. The beginning of each occurrence is the same, I mean, this is not goint to happen: blablabla_10_403,no_first_number_1. But this yes: blablabla_10_403,blablabla_hello_1. I mean, the format of all the words is the same: wordX_N or word_X_N (let's say that X can be a word or number and N is always number and always separated by "_"). I hope this clarifies the discussion a bit :)

Comment: Example: scaffold_2_30, scaffold_1_100, scaffold_2_10, scaffold_bla_300. Correct output should be: scaffold_1_100, scaffold_2_10, scaffold_2_30, scaffold_bla_300.